# Rails Localization - Translation Missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, localization

I have an application that I am trying to convert to use I18n for translation. I know that I18n is partially working because I see the language when I switch locales:

Translation missing: FR, agreement_search
Translation missing: EN, agreement_search

I have included the appropriate lines in the application.rb:

```
I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
I18n.default_locale = :en
```

I am calling the internationalization in my code like this:

```
<%= t('menu.agreement_search') %>
```

And I have defined my .YML file like this:

```
./config/locales/en.yml
en:
  menu:
    agreement_search:   'Agreement Search EN'
    agreement_views:    'Agreement Views EN'
    all_users:          'All Users EN'

./config/locales/fr.yml
fr:
  menu:
    agreement_search:   'Agreement Search FR'
    agreement_views:    'Agreement Views FR'
    all_users:          'All Users FR'
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I read in another answer that the problem could be with the formatting of the .YML but I don't see that there is anything wrong with my .YML formatting. I have even tried removing the 'menu' and putting all of my values at the top level.

Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: The line `I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]` is not necessary, that path is already included. Also, have you named your file `fr.yml`?

Comment: Yes, I have both an en.yml file and a fr.yml file. I can set my local to either EN or FR based on a DB column on User, but I just don't see the translated string, only "Translation Missing: FR, agreement_search", etc.

Comment: Can you explain better **which issue** you have? Is it raising an error? If yes, what error? If no, is it NOT translating to FR when you  set your locale to FR? Have you implemented a method to set locale in your app? If yes, it is setting the proper variable to the proper value? etc etc.

Comment: The issue is that I am not getting the translated string. On my page I see something like "Translation Missing: FR, agreement_search" when I should see the translated string for "Agreement Search". I have a method in my application.rb to set the locale -- it pulls the User locale from the User DB table. That part is working because I can set the locale to EN or FR and the error message changes from "Translation Missing: EN, agreement_search" to "Translation Missing: FR, agreement_search" respectively.

Comment: Could you provide more information about locale directory structure and filenames?

Comment: The files are in the locales directory and currently there is only en.yml and fr.yml

Answer (score 0):

Your default locale is set to `en` (in `application.rb`), but in your .YML file there is only `fr`. Probably that is the issue.

Comment: I have several .YML files for my application, one for each language I want to be able to use.

Answer (score 0):

By passing the local into the translate function it works. It must be a bug in the version of Rails I am using.

```
<% my_local = current_user.locale %>
<%= t('menu.agreement_search', :locale => my_locale) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same problem, and in my case the error was due to the use of `.yaml` extension file, rather than `.yml`. By default, rails will only look for `rb` and `yml` extension files.

For such a case, one can simply rename its files, or add `I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml,yaml}')]` in its application configuration.